# Remover valores duplicados de um array - php

Tags: php, array

Necessito remover os valores duplicados de um array em PHP, por exemplo:

```
$array = ('2015', '2015', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2014', '2016')
```

Gostaria que tivesse o output:

```
Array ( [0] => 2012 [1] => 2013 [2] => 2016 )
```

que fosse removido tudo o que é duplicado.

Tentei com `array_unique`, mas ele elimina o duplicado e mostra como único, sendo que preciso eliminar os dois.

Teria uma forma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se deseja apenas pegar os elementos do array que não se repetem use a função [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) ela retorna um array onde a chave são os valores do array de entrada e o valores são a quantia encontrada. Depois itera o array retornado e verifique se a ocorrência é igual a um.

Nesse exemplo `array_count_values()` devolve:

```
Array
(
    [2015] => 2
    [2012] => 1
    [2013] => 1
    [2014] => 2
    [2016] => 1
)
```

Código:

```
$array = array('2015', '2015', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2014', '2016');
$valores = array_count_values($array);

$novo = array();
foreach ($valores as $k => $v){
    if($v === 1) $novo[] = $k;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($novo);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2012
    [1] => 2013
    [2] => 2016
)
```

Comment: wow, perfeito!! muito obrigado @rray

Answer (score 3):

Uma variação funcional da [resposta aceita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/257486/137387):

```
<?php

$arr = ['2015', '2015', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2014', '2016'];

$res = array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values($arr), function($v){
   return $v == 1;
}));

print_r($res);

/*Array
(
    [0] => 2012
    [1] => 2013
    [2] => 2016
)*/
```

<sup>Teste o código no [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/Vud85x)</sup>

Onde:

1. São [contados as ocorrências](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-count-values.php) de cada valor no array.
   `Array([2015] => 2,[2014] => 2, [2012] => 1, [2013] => 1, [2016] => 1)`
2. São [filtrados](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php) apenas os que não se repetem.
   `Array([2012] => 1, [2013] => 1,[2016] => 1)`
3. As [chaves do array](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-keys.php) resultante é a solução do problema.
   `Array([0] => 2012, [1] => 2013, [2] => 2016)`

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro criamos 2 funções para limpar e remover os valores duplicados:

```
function limpaValoresDuplicados($num) {
    if($num<=1) return $num;
}

function removeValoresDuplicados($num) {
    if(!empty($num)) return $num;
}
```

Chamamos então nosso array() e solicitamos as funções criadas:

```
$array = array('2015', '2015', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2014', '2016');

$valores = array_count_values($array);
$valores = array_map("limpaValoresDuplicados",$valores);
$valores = array_filter($valores, removeValoresDuplicados);
```

Retorno:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($valores);
echo "</pre>";

Array
(
    [2012] => 1
    [2013] => 1
    [2016] => 1
)
```